# How do I set a timeout in load Jquery for this particular example?

Tags: jquery, javascript, jquery-load

How do I set a timeout in load for this very particular example where I pass data with a string ?  It looks like the google charts supposed to be loaded from compare_proc.php api are taking long ... because on the click event , I get a blank result and I'm expecting charts to be loaded from compare.php .. I'd appreciate how I can set a timeout for this particular Jquery operation. Thanks !

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          $("#opposition a").click(function(e) {
          var first_id  = $(this).attr('id');
          var second_id = $("h1").attr('id');
          $("div#test").load('compare_proc.php','id=' + first_id + '&id2=' + second_id);
          e.preventDefault();
            });
});
```

Comment: try calling  `http://api.jquery.com/delay/` delay() on google charts function.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery `load()` method doesn't accept any `settings` param. So you have to replace it with more low-level method [**ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call - which lets you specify `timeout` settings for this specific request. One possible way to do it:

```
$.ajax('compare_proc.php', {
  data: 'id=' + first_id + '&id2=' + second_id,
  timeout: someTimeoutInMs,
  success: function(resp) {
    $('#test').html(resp);
  }
});
```

The alternative is to leave your code as is, but modify global AJAX settings instead with [**ajaxSetup()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) call (prior to calling `load`). Note that using this API is strongly discouraged on its very documentation page:

> The settings specified here will affect *all calls* to `$.ajax` or
>   AJAX-based derivatives such as `$.get()`. This can cause undesirable
>   behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend
>   against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the
>   call or define a simple plugin to do so.

Still, in your case (when only timeout settings are changed) it may be ok to go that way as well.

Comment: @raina77now .. Could you give me an example of how I could integrate my example in ajax() ?