# JQuery Newbie: Do I Need a setTimeout for long running function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I 'm working on a web app that has the option to collect many data points. This operation can take as long as 10-15 minutes.

I've written some JQuery, to load div's in a call back chain.
However, it appears that if the function takes too long to complete, the
call backs load anyways.

I suspect another error may be the culprit and have added more error logging and checks.

I'd still like to know if this behavior can be attributed to a timeout issue ?

Cheers

EDIT: Fixed syntax issues
Assuming my syntax is correct, is it still possible that a long runtime of the above mentioned function, would cause a problem ?

Or is this more likely to be a bug or unhandled error ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("alert('timeout');", 800000)

$(function() {
    $("#chart").load("/run_analysis/", function() {
        $("#stem").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="chart">Collecting Data</div>

<div id=stem style="display: none">
<a href="/stem/">Single Word Analysis</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what this for :-> setTimeout("alert('timeout');", 800000)

Comment: That's probably a very silly attempt to avoid a timeout from a long running method in Flask, that takes ~15 minutes to return ( in some use cases ).

Comment: Couldn't your server be returning an error because of the long running function? the callback you pass in to `load()` is executed regardless of the response's status code. maybe you could `console.log` whatever data is sent back (similar to http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-1 ) to see what's going on?

Comment: The call back for load will only be called when the url has loaded. it has nothing to do with settimeout. See in requests tab in chrome dev tool. what is response for  get /run_analysis/.

Comment: I believe that I've avoided the server error, by rendering the page first, then calling the function ( in Flask ), via JQuery. I do not get a server timeout error. What happens, is that after about 6 minutes, the other div get's 'toggled', and shows up, but 'run_analysis' did not complete. There would be an output on the server if it had.

Comment: @rishabhdev I will try that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the timeout function if the `.load` complete successfully. Is that what you want?

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ alert("timeout"); }, 800000);
$("#chart").load("/run_analysis/", function() {
    $("#stem").slideDown("fast");
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `status` parameter of the `.load` callback

```
$("#chart").load("/run_analysis/", function(response,status,xhr) {
    if (status == "timeout")
        alert("Timed out...");
    if (status == "success")        
        $("#stem").slideDown("fast");
});
```

You should probably use the `.ajax` syntax if you want to specify the `timeout` in ms. I'm not sure if you can do that directly with `.load`. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129303/2278598)

Comment: I think that maybe what I want. Also, I'd to know the how the load function behaves, if the function loaded, takes such a long time.

Comment: The callback function for [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) can come back with some optional parameters, including `status`. So, you could check that when it returns, it can be "success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror". You can probably use `timeout` for your situation. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/ajax_load.asp) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. My primary concern, is understanding if  long running functions cause some kind of timeout error. If they do, how do I fix that ?

Comment: I don't thing long functions will cause any inherent problems. If it's an asynchronous call like in your situation, it might timeout

Comment: What exactly are you loading in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98948/discussion-between-wbg-and-andrew-brooke).